# Alternative to SoapExtension.ChainStream when moving from ASMX to WCF

Tags: web-services, wcf

I'm in the process of upgrading a client from using the ASMX proxy to WCF. Important to note is that I do not have control of the server side implementation or interface.
The process was fairly easy, however, with ASMX we were using a SoapExtension to access the network stream directly. I've done some research but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this with WCF. One option could be to write a custom transport channel, but that seems to be quite a lot of work to achieve something fairly simple.
Any other ideas out there?

**Update**: In response to why do I need to write directly to the network stream:
Long story. I'll try to explain briefly.
I'm working with a server that has an MTOM interface to upload a file. I have no control whatsoever on the server or its source code. Unfortunately, the generated WCF proxy uses a byte array for the file contents. This is a problem with large files since the entire file must be loaded into memory, and especially in a 32bit process and the LOH fragmentation I quickly get an OutOfMemoryException with files just several 100's of MB.
Previously when using ASMX proxy, I came up with a clever trick to solve this:
Instead of writing the contents of the file directly to the byte[] property, I write the path of the source file. I then intercept the message just before it is sent over the network stream and replace this path with the file contents, only this time reading and sending the data in chunks.
This is only possible when I have access to the network stream. Otherwise, attempting to manipulate the message this way just loads the entire file into memory which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do something similar by using an IClientMessageInspector.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector(v=vs.110).aspx

It gives you access to the raw message when sending and receiving.

Comment: That allows me to manipulate the message but does not write directly to the network stream.

Comment: Why do you need to write directly to the network stream?

Comment: The reply was too long, so I updated my question with more details on the why.